# PythonでのWebスクレイピングで、データが抽出できない

Tags: python, web-scraping

Pythonでwebスクレイピングを行っているのですが, 抽出したいデータが出力されません.

サイトは, 日本酒オンライン販売のサイトで、商品名・価格・醸造元・アルコール度数・精米歩合などのデータを抽出したいと考えております.

Visual Studio Code
バージョン: 1.83.0 (Universal)
使用したOS：macOS

以下にコードを添付します.

```
import scrapy
import logging

class DesktopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'desktop'
    allowed_domains = ['www.haruyama-sake.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.haruyama-sake.com/smp/list.php?type=search&stockSort=0&pict=1&search=720ml&page=1']

    def parse(self, response):
       logging.info(response.url)
       products=response.xpath('.//li[contains(@class,"itemlist_bottom")]')
       for product in products:
           maker=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"mp_item_item4")/text()').get()
           name=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"item_item1")/text()').get()
           price=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"price mp_item_item5")/text()').get()
           yield{
               'メーカー':maker,
               '商品名':name,
               '価格':price,
           }

       next_page=response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]')
       if next_page:
           yield response.follow(url=next_page[0], callback=self.parse)
```

このコードを実行すると、ファイル内に何も出力されませんでした。
urlとxpathを変更して違うサイトで実行した場合は正常にデータが抽出されました。
データが抽出されるようにするには、どのようにしたら良いでしょうか.
ご回答お待ちしております.

Comment: クラス・メソッドの定義や抽出したい情報が何かだけではなく、使い方・呼び出し方や、結果がどのような形(ファイルや表示)になれば良いのかといった情報もできるだけ詳細を追記してみてください。提示されたソースコードだけではクラスが定義されただけで何も実行はされないと思うのですが。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 例えば「urlとxpathを変更して違うサイトで実行した場合は正常にデータが抽出されました。」と言う時に、どんなソースコードでどこのサイトや情報を使ったのか、その結果はどうだったのかが示されていると何かヒントになるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for product in products` ループ下で指定してしているXPathの文法が間違っています。

### 前提

Scrapyを使い、「`scrapy runspider`でスクレイピングを実施した際に発生しした事象」としたうえでの回答です。

### 詳細

Scrapyを最小構成でセットアップした上で、質問文のコードをSpider用のモジュールとして実行すると、下記のようなエラーが出ていることが分かります。
（もしエラー出力を見る環境が無いなら、きちんと用意して実行してログを見ることを勧めます）

```text
  File "/path/to/desktop.py", line 13, in parse
    maker=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"mp_item_item4")/text()').get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/path/to/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 650, in xpath
    raise ValueError(f"XPath error: {exc} in {query}")
ValueError: XPath error: Invalid predicate in .//div[contains(@class,"mp_item_item4")/text()
```

"Invalid predicate" = "無効な述語"とある通り、実際にエラーとなっている箇所のXPathの文法を確認すると、本来`div`クラスの詳細な指定をしている角括弧(`[`)が閉じられていません。
この部分を編集するだけで、この行でのエラーは発生しなくなります。

```python
# maker=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"mp_item_item4")/text()').get()
  maker=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"mp_item_item4")]/text()').get()
#                                                             ↑括弧を閉じる
```

さて、再び`scrapy runspider`を実行すると、まだ同種のエラーが出ることが分かります。
改めてコードを確認するとわかるのですが、`for product in products`配下で記述している全てXPathにおいて角括弧が閉じられていません。

```python
# 元コード
maker=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"mp_item_item4")/text()').get()
name=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"item_item1")/text()').get()
price=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"price mp_item_item5")/text()').get()
# 正しいコード
maker=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"mp_item_item4")]/text()').get()
name=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"item_item1")]/text()').get()
price=product.xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"price mp_item_item5")]/text()').get()
```

上記の通り適切な文法なXPathを指定することにより、`scrapy runspider`が正常に終了するようになります。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
ご指摘いただいたことを元にいくつか修正したところ無事にほしいデータを得ることができました。ありがとうございました。